# Understanding notation in $-\overline{U}_LmU_R+\text{h.c.} =-\overline{U}mU$

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, gauge-theory, chirality

Suppose $U$ is a field with left handed and right handed parts $U_L,U_R $, respectively.

When discussing Lagrangians, I keep finding the following simplification step

$$-\overline{U}_LmU_R+\text{h.c.} =-\overline{U}mU\tag{Eq. 1}$$

Where the field $U$ is just

$$U=U_L+U_R\tag{Eq. 2}$$

I can't seem to understand how Eq. 1 is true. Using Eq. 2 in $-\overline{U}mU$ we find:
\begin{align*}
-\overline{U}mU &= -\overline{(U_L+U_R)}m(U_L+U_R)\\
 &= - \left( \overline{U}_LmU_R+\overline{U}_RmU_L+\overline{U}_LmU_L+\overline{U}_RmU_R \right) \tag{Eq. 3}
\end{align*}
Do we get rid of the last 2 terms in Eq. 3? If so, how?

Or is it that I'm understanding the use of $+\text{h.c.}$ wrong? From what I understand, the fully written version of the left hand side of Eq. 1 is:
$$-\overline{U}_LmU_R+\text{h.c.} \equiv -\overline{U}_LmU_R-\overline{U}_RmU_L\tag{Eq. 4}$$

Answer (score 0):

This comes from what you mean by $\overline{U}$. I follow the notation of Peskin Chapter 3 with $\sigma^\mu=(1,\vec{\sigma}),\overline{\sigma}^\mu=(1,-\vec{\sigma})$ and $\gamma^\mu = \left(\begin{array}{cc}0 &\sigma^\mu \\\overline{\sigma}^\mu&0\end{array}\right),\gamma^5=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 &0 \\0&-1\end{array}\right)$ and $U=\left(\begin{array}{cc}U_L \\U_R\end{array}\right)$ and $\overline{U}=U^\dagger\gamma^0$. You may simply take the mass term as $mU_L^\dagger U_R$ or equivalently write it as   $m\overline{U_L} U_R$ where the $U_L,U_R$ here are defined via $U_{L,R}=P_{L,R}U,P_{L,R}=\frac{1\pm\gamma^5}{2}$, i.e.  $\left(\begin{array}{cc}U_L \\0\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{cc}0 \\U_R\end{array}\right)$.

Obviously $mU_L^\dagger U_R+h.c. = m\left(\begin{array}{cc}U_L^\dagger&U_R^\dagger\end{array}\right)\gamma^0 \left(\begin{array}{cc}U_L \\U_R\end{array}\right)=m\overline{U}U$ you could get the correct answer. Alternatively, taking the notation you used, you will also find $\overline{U}_{i}U_{i}=U_i^\dagger\gamma^0U_i=U^\dagger P_i\gamma^0P_iU$. Because $\{\gamma^5,\gamma^0\}=0,P_R\gamma^0=\gamma^0P_L,P_L\gamma^0=\gamma^0P_R$ , and further use $P_RP_L=P_LP_R=0$ we find that $\overline{U}_{i}U_{i}=0$, so the two terms in your Eq.3 are indeed zero.